# Display direction information gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am able to display the route on the map in my rails app using the [gmaps4rails gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/gmaps4rails) but I can't get info such as *drive time and distance* to display anywhere.

The [wiki](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Direction) talks about displaying a panel but I havent gotten that to work either.

```
<div id="instructions"></div>
<%= gmaps("map_options" => {
    "zoom" => 14,
    "auto_adjust" => false,
    "center_latitude" => @location.latitude,
    "center_longitude" => @location.longitude
  },
  "markers" => { "data" => @json },
  "direction"   => { 
    "data" => {
      "from" => @location.address,
      "to" => "Cleveland, OH"
    },
    "travelMode" => "DRIVING",
    "display_panel" => true,
    "panel_id" => "instructions"
  }) %>
```

Comment: You need an element with the Id "instructions" inside the document.

Comment: @Dr.Molle notice the first line where I specify the div id. Still doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry, haven't seen it

Comment: It looks like this is no longer a supported feature(?) and the gem has changed functionality.